# what does %(parameter)s means here

Tags: python, sql, wildcard

I have a code snippet like this. I am confused about the use of %()s.
If it is used to format parameters,
shouldn't we use  %(threshold)d for threshold since it's a number?

```
def recommendations_for_user(user_id, threshold=4.5):
  # Join with the courses table
  query = """
  SELECT title, rating FROM recommendations
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = recommendations.course_id
    WHERE user_id=%(user_id)s AND rating>%(threshold)s
    ORDER BY rating DESC
  """
  # Add the threshold parameter
  predictions_df = pd.read_sql(query, db_engine, params = {"user_id": user_id, 
                                                           "threshold": threshold})
  return predictions_df.title.values

# Try the function you created
print(recommendations_for_user(12, 4.65))
```

Comment: That isn't (only) SQL. [Edit] the question and tag the host language and/or framework.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3):

%(threshold)s and %(threshold)d will do the same but %(threshold)d will just force the format.

%s wil call str(arg) where as %d will call int(arg) before calling str().

so for %d it will be str(int(arg)) which will cause error if arg is not a valid number. %s will not raise any error.

So if you are sure that threshold will always be a valid number you can use %(threshold)s.